# Recursive similarity between trees according to the number of common subtrees in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am stufying Prolog using SWI Prolog and I am finding many difficult with this code snippet that found if 2 binary trees have N common subtree (having the same root):

```
/* BASE CASE: T1 and T2 are two tree composed of only the root X so it is
             TRUE that they have exactly one common subtree
*/
delta(tree(X,[]),tree(X,[]),1):- !.

/* RULE: T1 and T2 are DIFFERENT and are structured tree.
         It is TRUE that T1 and T2 have N subtrees if it is TRUE that:
*/
delta(tree(X,RX),tree(X,RX1),N):- sons(RX,SX), 
                                  sons(RX1,SX)
                              subdelta(RX,RX1,N), 
                                  !.
/* Else whatever T1 and T2 it is true that they have 0 common tree
   (here we are in the case that the previous delta\2 predicate are 
   boot failed) 
*/
delta(_,_,0):- !.

subdelta([],[],1).

subdelta([T1|R1],[T2|R2], N):-
    delta(T1,T2,N1),
    subdelta(R1,R2, NR),
    N is (1 + N1)*NR.
```

I think that the **delta/3** predicate it is true  if the first tree have N common subtrees with the second tree

He rappresent the tree in this way:

```
tree(F, LIST_OF_SUBTREES).
```

So for example this is a tree composed by a root X and two leaves u and v:

```
tree(x, [tree(u,[]), tree(v,[])])
```

I think that the **delta/3** predicate it is declined into the 3 possible cases:

**1) T1 and T2 are two tree composed of only the root X so it is TRUE that they have exactly one common subtree**

**2) T1 and T2 are DIFFERENT and are structured tree that have more levels so it is TRUE that T1 and T2 have N subtrees if it is TRUE that: ?!?!

**3) Else, if both the prevuous delta\2 predicate are failed, whatever T1 and T2 it is true that they have 0 common tree**

I think that this interpretation is correct (I hope so...) but I have some difficulties to understand the second rule: what could be **sons/2** predicate (it seems to me that this is note a SWI Prolog built in predicate and I have no its implementation on the slide where I am studyin)

What is for you? And what is it's logic?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of the three rules seems reasonable to me. For comparison, I would rephrase them as:

1. `delta(T1, T2, 1)` holds if T1 and T2 have the same value and are empty (leaf nodes).
2. `delta(T1, T2, N)` holds if T1 and T2 have N common subtrees.
3. `delta(T1, T2, 0)` holds if T1 and T2 have 0 common subtrees.

I'm unclear on why these cuts are necessary. I suppose they're green cuts, because a pair of trees can't have 1, N and 0 common subtrees simultaneously.

`sons/2` is interesting. I could imagine it working a few different ways. One thing we know for sure is that if two trees have common subtrees, `sons/2` should generate the same value; it must work that way because otherwise `sons(RX, SX), sons(RX1, SX)` wouldn't ever work. (Note that there's a missing comma on that line).

One question that remains is, does `sons/2` work by generating *all* the subtrees, or just the nearest pair? It seems likely to me that it generates the nearest pair only, because `subdelta/3` calls `delta/3`, leading to indirect recursion. If `sons/2` generated all subtrees, this would result in unbounded recursion or at least a lot of unnecessary work. So I would bet that `sons/2` looks like this:

```
sons(tree(_,Children), X) :- member(X, Children).
```

This suggests at least one case where `delta/3` is going to do something more intelligent than one would expect at first blush: the case where T1 and T2 are reflections of each other. `sons/2` of T1 and T2 will unify the left with the right and then the right with the left, so you'll get the maximal similarity from sharing subtrees but not exact structure.

What's most surprising to me about this is that `delta/3` doesn't seem to be counting *differences*, it seems to be counting *similarities*. This isn't what one would expect from the name, but it follows from the implementation. And it's hard to imagine how one would count differences directly--what is the upper limit? With files, for instance, you can count the differences by saying, each line could be the same (0) or different (1) and then adding up the differences.

Hope this is on the right track and helps!

Comment: I still find this topic very hard but thanks to your help now I think that I have new bases to reason about this problem !!!

This is not all clear for me but in the next days I will reason about it and later I will ask for any other doubts :-)

Comment: I think you're improving, but you need to have a little more faith in yourself.

Comment: My biggest problem is that I could not take the course because I was working and this is my last universitary exame...so I get anxiety :-)

Comment: That explains a lot actually. I was wondering how you could be in a class and need this much help, but if you're going it alone it's instead impressive that you're getting this far this fast. :)

Comment: also considers that I work in office 2 nights at week (from 23 to 7) consequently being stoned 3 days a week ... :-/
I have to end universitary and will find a new job hehe

Comment: stoned not in the sense that I am under some drugs...but in the sense that after two entire night at work every week for many months at a time...Well, the feeling is similar: you feel down and confused for all the next day bleah :-/